# Best way to display widgets outside of the main Scaffold?

Tags: flutter, flutter-material, flutter-scaffold

I want to display a sidebar to the right of the entire `Scaffold`, such that when the user navigates between routes in the `Scaffold`, for example using `Navigator.of(context).pushNamed()`, the sidebar should be unaffected. In the sidebar, I also need to have a button that displays widgets in front of the entire `Scaffold`.

It seems simple enough to just use the `MaterialApp`'s `builder`-method to surround the entire app with a `Row` and possibly a `Stack` (to be able to display things in front of the `Scaffold`). The problem is that there seem to be a few puzzle pieces missing when using the `builder` method, for example `Overlay` and `Material`. If I add them manually, it seems to work.

```
builder: (context, child) {
  return Overlay(
    initialEntries: [
      OverlayEntry(builder: (context){
        return Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(child: child),
            Material(child: MySideBar()),
          ],
        );
      })
    ],
  );
},
```

Is this a good way to structure this kind of app? It honestly feels kind of sketchy. Is there a better approach, or even an `official` way to do it?

Comment: Does the NavigationRail widget not serve your needs for a persistent sidebar? https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/NavigationRail-class.html

Comment: @CStark No, and even if it did it doesn't answer the question of what the preferred solution would be to place it outside the `Scaffold`. I'm not asking about how to make a sidebar, I'm asking about the best way to place it outside the `Scaffold` and still have full and reliable functionality of the app.